# cannot import name in a file?

Tags: django, django-views, command-prompt

Hello I am trying to run my django application but its saying: cannot import name 'd' from 'niu' (C:\Users\amber\Umaido\niu_*init*_.py) which is strange. I have created d in my code file:
[[image: enter image description here: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/75DFL.png)]

```
 import datetime
d=datetime.date(2023,8,27)
t=datetime.time(21,15)
def check(d,t):
    a = datetime.datetime.combine(d, t)
    ok = a.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    formate_now = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    if ok==formate_now:
        return True
    else: return False
print(check(d,t))
```

and importet it than into views.py (
[image]

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from Code import d,t,check


def New_Year_Check(request):
    if check(d,t)==True:
        return render(request,"hi/yes.html")
    else:
        return render(request,"hi/No.html")
```

The problem now is that it usually works on the Terminal but my Command prompt Terminal is telling me that its an error.

I have tried to change form code import d to from . import d but it does not work either

> Blockquote    from . import views
> File "C:\Users\amber\Umaido\niu\views.py", line 3, in 
> from code import d,t,check
> ImportError: cannot import name 'd' from 'code' (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\code.py)

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Comment: Also share the full traceback.

Comment: alright sir i am gonna edit the code

Answer (score 0):

You should import from the `niu.code`, so:

```
from niu.code import check, d, t
```

You probably have set the project root to the wrong directory in the IDE: this should be the parent of `niu`, not `niu` itself.

That being said, if you want to check that a `date` and `time` combination is the same up to the minute, you can check with:

```
from datetime import datetime


def check(d, t):
    return (
        datetime.combine(d, t).timetuple()[:5] == datetime.now().timetuple()[:5]
    )
```

This is typically faster, and more straightforward.

combining a date and time has an important caveat: depending on the timezone, certain dates can have certain times twice, so a `datetime` is "richer" than a `date` and `time` combination.

Comment: wow who would have thought,hat it would be that simple... But Thanks!!!!